# Displaying the contents of a cell based on the max fuction

Tags: excel-formula

I am running a MAX function of a ***row*** of data such as:

```
+------+-----+------+------+-------+------+------+--------+------+------+--------+------+
| John | Doe | 4323 | Eric | Smith | 1235 | Sean | Wilson | 4567 | Jeff | French | 3212 |
+------+-----+------+------+-------+------+------+--------+------+------+--------+------+
```

(with each item being in a different cell)

Naturally the MAX function running on this whole row will return the 4567.  I would like the cell in front of the MAX result to return the first name that directly proceeds the result such as:

Sean 4567

Keep in mind that the first name, last name and the number are in separate columns but on the same row, but always located in a cell a constant number of cells before the result. (I don't need nor want the last name for this result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have your values at row 4, from Column D to O.

The following will get you the name (Sean) instead of the MAX value (4567):

```
=INDEX(D4:O4,MATCH(MAX(D4:O4),D4:O4,0)-2)
```

The `MATCH` formula will return position 9, the `INDEX` formula will return the value at position 9. We want to return position  7, so subtract 2 and the `INDEX` will return "correct" result. The `-2` is how many positions the return values should be offset (2 cells before the actually MAX value is found).

If you want Sean 4567 I should combine the the two formulas:

```
=INDEX(D4:O4,MATCH(MAX(D4:O4),D4:O4;0)-2) &" "& INDEX(D4:O4,MATCH(MAX(D4:O4),D4:O4,0))
```

Or

```
=INDEX(D4:O4,MATCH(MAX(D4:O4),D4:O4,0)-2) &" "& MAX(D4:O4)
```

[image]

You already mention it, it only works if the offset is constant across the row (Name is always located 2 cells before value cell).

Comment: I attempted this solution:
=INDEX(D4:O4;MATCH(MAX(D4:O4);D4:O4;0)-2) (changing the MAX range in each position to match my data (E4:EM4)
I continually get a formula error at the first O4 position.  I even recreated your example sheet exactly to troubleshoot, but no dice.  Ideas?

Comment: I think it's because I use "`;`" as a delimiter (I live in Europe) while in US it's "`,`". Try this in your example: `=INDEX(D4:O4,MATCH(MAX(D4:O4),D4:O4,0)-2)`. So switch all "`;` to "`,`" and it should work for you. I apologize for the inconvenience!!!

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your delimiter settings :)!

Comment: It DID solve the issue!  Thank you so much for an easy solution to the problem!

Comment: Happy to help :)!!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Wizhi said, but slightly shorter. Assuming the info is on row 1:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;MATCH(MAX(1:1);1:1) - 2))`

Where your row number number is given (1:1), col number finds the max and goes 2 before (the given offset), and INDIRECT(ADDRESS()) concatenates it with the row number and finds the name there ('Sean', in this case.)